# How do I keep current item in view in an overflown div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with a fixed height of 400px and a long list of items inside. Clicking on prev/next links will move you throught the list. The problem is, after a while, the current item will be out of view. How can I move the scrollbar with the current item?

I've made a demo, have a look: http://jsbin.com/idunaf

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <style>
   #listContainer{height:400px;width:300px;overflow:auto;background-color:#eee;}
   .selectedItem{background-color:white;color:red;}
 </style>

<script class="jsbin" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

  for(var a=[],i=0;i<100;++i){
      a[i]=i;
  }

  currentItem = 0;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var items = [];
    $.each(a, function(i,x){

      items.push('<li id="item_'+x+'">item #'+x+'</li>');

    });

    $('#list').append(items.join(''));

    $('#next').click(function() { updateList(); currentItem += 1; });
    $('#prev').click(function() { updateList(); currentItem -= 1; });

  });

  function updateList(){
     $('#listContainer').find('.selectedItem').removeClass('selectedItem');
     $('#item_'+currentItem).addClass('selectedItem');
  }
</script>

</head>
<body>

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="prev"><< PREV ITEM</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="next">NEXT ITEM >></a>

  <div id="listContainer">
      <ul id="list"></ul>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the (non-jQuery) DOM method [`element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView):

```
$('#item_'+currentItem).addClass('selectedItem')[0].scrollIntoView(true);

// or
$('#item_'+currentItem)[0].scrollIntoView(true);
// or
document.getElementById('item_'+currentItem).scrollIntoView(true);
```

The `[0]` is just to get a reference to the actual DOM element from the jQuery object - given you're selecting by id I assume there can only ever be one element matching the selector. Of course with most jQuery methods setup to allow chaining you can do this on the end of the existing `.addClass()` rather than selecting the element again.

(Have a look at the [`.scrollIntoView()` doco](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView) to decide whether to pass true or false (or nothing) to the method.)

Comment: This works but is it possible to make the current item stay in the center of the div, instead of top/bottom?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to update my answer with details, but if you google "jquery scrollintoview" you'll find various solutions (including some on SO) that (I assume) calculate the appropriate y offset and use the [jQuery `.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) method...jQuery would (optionally) make it easy to animate the scroll too. Also you can check if the current item is already showing and if so don't change the scroll position.

Comment: Ok, this will suffice until I find a solution to that. Thanks.